# Setting a Cap in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, auto-increment

I'm trying to set a cap of 10 on a particular cell, "Available". We can only hold 10 of this product at a time, and receive 1 at the beginning of each month. The "Available" cell currently has 2 inputs. The first input, "Accumulated", increases by 1 at the beginning of every month. The other, "Used", is incremented manually when the product is used. "Available" = "Accumulated" - "Used". Here is an example[Example of Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbxX9.png)

The problem I am having is in the last row, where it has 19 accumulated and 0 used. If I were to set up a formula in the "Available" cell to cap at 10 with something like,
`MIN(10,"Accumulated"-"Used")`
it would stay at 10 even if the "Used" number increases, but I need it to go down to 9, because we will not have another product in stock until the beginning of the next month.

I feel like if I could make another column that shows how many time we would have received a new product, but we could not store it, that would fix the problem. How would I create that column, and just increment it each month that the available is already at 10?

Comment: It seems wrong to say Accumulated increases by one each month.  It shouldn't increase if it is already at 10, due to your cap?  Can the formula for Accumulated be changed to say if Available is at 10, Accumulated doesn't increase?

Comment: We use the Accumulated column to keep track of how many months that product has been coming in for a client. I guess we could keep that as a separate column, and only have the Available column staying up to date. I had not considered that before. The question is then, what formula would I use so if it gets to 11, it stays at 10, but then when I add 1 to the used column it goes down to 9, and does not stay at 10.

Comment: It might help if you shared a sheet with sample data.  Is your picture based on one row per product?  If it is meant to be a snap shot in time, ie the situation today, without historical data, I don't think you'll be able to do this without code.  If there are historical data records that have a date when the last item was used, and a date when the product updates were delivered (start of the month?), then maybe formulas could be used.  But what is your workflow?  Is a user going to manually increment the #Used by 1 at some point?  And you want the #Available to then get updated by formula?

Comment: Each row is a different client. The #Used is updated manually, always moving up when a product is used. How do I add a file here? Here are the formulas I am using: Date, =(DATEDIF(A2,TODAY(),"M")+1), Used Number, =B2-C2

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need the following formula

```
=IF(N5-O5<9,N5-O5,MIN(9,N5-O5))
```

[image]

Comment: Was his other point that if they then "used" the product on row 12, updating the 2 to a 3, the available value would still stay at 9 with your formula?  I'm having trouble figuring out an effective process flow using these columns - to track inventory somehow, but this doesn't sem to work... How can Accumulated have got to 19 (or even above 10) if they don't accept delivery of the product once they've got 10 in stock?

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I am trying to get at. I cannot think of a way that would overcome this automatically in this format. I did see in your earlier comment that maybe I should not include the Accumulated column in the formula, and just have the Available column, keeping track. I have not solved it yet, but I think that is probably where I need to start.